# how to stream a video in h264?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to stream my video into `h264`, so I can play it on a `html5` page through `video` tag. I have found a lot of examples showing how to stream  a video file to `rtmp` stream. but I can barely find a example  for `h264`.

Here is the only example I can find:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Virtual-Camera" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://10.1.0.102:1234
```

This seems fits to my need. But I don't know what kind of server `udp://10.1.0.102:1234` is.

If it starts with `rtmp://10.1.0.102`, then I know  it's a `rtmp` server, and I have to setup a `nginx` and a `rtmp` module. But what's a `udp` server? What do I have to do to setup one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ffmpeg command line allows streaming over MPEG2-TS over UDP.
So it acts as a live encoder, and that's not a bad choice for live encoder.

So you have a live encoder in place, but to stream to a web page, you also need a streaming server software, that will ingest (receive) this live stream, and will convert it to a format playable by HTML5 video tag. The format is likely to be WebRTC.

You can use Wowza or Unreal Media Server - they will ingest your MPEG2-TS stream and output to webpage as WebRTC stream.

Comment: Emmm, There are some new words for me, I need some hours to learn them, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

UDP:// is not a streaming format as such, but tells you it's serving the stream over UDP (instead of TCP). The format is actually MPEG-TS (which you can see from `-f mpegts`)

If you want to play it in a normal browser, you will need to provide it in a different format. for live video, there isn't really a universally supported format that you can just use with the  tag. Microsoft Edge and Apple Safari both support HLS natively, but both Chrome and Firefox lack any native support for a live streaming format.

With HLS, you can use hls.js and get playback in pretty much all browsers. ffmpeg can natively [output HLS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#HTTPLiveStreamingandStreamingwithmultiplebitrates), you would just need a web server as well then.

Comment: thanks for the help, HLS seems doesn't fit me. It needs to split video in ts pieces, that is the least thing I wanna do. Convert those video in H264 mp4 seems a better way, they can be played via <video> tag. But I'm too lazy to deal with hundreds of videos.

Comment: @somereason well, if it's not for live videos. Then yeah, mp4's work just fine. You can't really do that for live though. Why do you not want to have the stream split in to smaller segments though?

Comment: @colde - " for live video, there isn't really a universally supported format that you can just use with the tag" - out of date. WebRTC is universally supported.

Comment: @colde I had an idea, I want to build a site which can play my movies like youtube. But the difficult part is, movie files are not in uniform format, mostly are mkv and mp4. If I want to play them through html page, the first option is convert them into mp4, another is to stream to rtmp or h264 the while playing. I really thought the second option would save my time. and I'm wrong about that.  Currently, I have setup an IIS site, so each movie will have a url, I copy those url to my VLC player, it works well. but as you see, That's not convenient,

Comment: @user1390208 It is, but it isn't usable by just putting a URL into a <video> tag. It requires a bit more setup. But point taken, that it might be useful in this context.

Comment: @somereason right, for that, the path of least resistance would absolutely be to convert all of them to mp4s (with h.264 video and aac audio). That's just about the simplest way to achieve that i can think of.

Comment: @colde I just got a way, I found a server named  [livego](https://github.com/gwuhaolin/livego) which be able to convert rtmp into http-flv, so I  can use ffmpeg to push stream into this server, then use [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) to play. but unfortunately, livego is not stable enough, and live stream is really not suitable for playing movie. so I think I should try to develop a tool to convert my movie files into h.264.